# Arduino Pro Mini with Current Sensor ACS712

Tags: arduino

I am trying to use an ACS712 (30 A) current sensor with an Arduino Pro Mini (5V), starting with simple analogRead measurement. There is a 40 Watts lamp connected to the sensor which gives me around 700 mA when using a multimeter to measure.

Here is the code, as simple as possible.

---

**void setup() {**

```
Serial.begin(9600);

pinMode(A1, INPUT);    *<<------ Already tested without this line.*

delay(3000);
```

}

**void loop() {**

```
Serial.println(analogRead(A1));
delay(500);
```

}

---

The problem is the result:

**0
13
796
536
592
131
183
0
0
1023
939
18
482
430
146
0
0
752
1023
154
269
949
36
202
0
0
1023
502
60
1023**

I know that there should have some adjustments to have the correct "ampère" values, but for now, I just would like to understand how the sensor works.

Question is: shouldn´t the value be more stable than that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you measure are values of the sine wave of the AC (alternating current).

Usual is to use [the RMS value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current#Mathematics_of_AC_voltages) of the current (power, voltage).

I have this function to measure the RMS value from the sensor readings:

```
/**
 * return value is RMS of sampled values
 */
int readElSens() {

  const int ELSENS_ANALOG_MIDDLE_VALUE = 512;
  const int RMS_INT_SCALE = 10;

  unsigned long long sum = 0;
  int n = 0;
  unsigned long start_time = millis();
  while (millis() - start_time < 200) { // in 200 ms measures 10 50Hz AC oscillations
    long v = (short) analogRead(ELSENS_PIN) - ELSENS_ANALOG_MIDDLE_VALUE;
    sum += v * v;
    n++;
  }
  return sqrt((double) sum / n) * RMS_INT_SCALE;
}
```

Then you can calculate the RMS current amperes from the value returned by this function.